# Grouping by List Values and find total number of elements which is used in List

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have one `List<<Map<String, Object>>` which contains below values in List :
Map<String, Object> contains two keys resourceName and tableName as per below attached image:

```
Map<String, Object> m1 = new HashMap<>();
m1.put("resourceName", "Pt");
m1.put("tableName", "Tb1");

Map<String, Object> m2 = new HashMap<>();
m2.put("resourceName", "Pt");
m2.put("tableName", "Tb2");

Map<String, Object> m3 = new HashMap<>();
m3.put("resourceName", "Enc");
m3.put("tableName", "Enctab1");
```

I want output as mentioned below (i.e., Number of tablenames per resource:)

**[Pt, 2]
[Enc, 1]**

Comment: please use the code format editing of OS, **never** post pictures of code

Comment: @Ivan, Thanks for your response. I replaced code image with code snippet. Do you have any idea about the solution for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
List<Map<String, Object>> list = // ...

Map<Object, Long> frequencies = list.stream()
                                    .map(Map::values)
                                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                    .collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
```

---

Make sure to have these imports:

```java
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following things are important here:

1. to select and count entries by specific key `"resourceName"` in the maps,
2. to represent the output in the required format by converting `Map.Entry` to String

```java
String result = list.stream()
    .map(m -> m.get("resourceName")) // retrieve specific 'field' from map
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(  // calculate frequency of values
        name -> name, 
        Collectors.summingInt(name -> 1)
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> Arrays.toString(new Object[]{e.getKey(), e.getValue()}))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
[Pt, 2][Enc, 1]
```